# How to get google map view with housing outlines?

Tags: maps

on this application, you type in your home address, and the map changes to a view with outlines for each house? Do any of you know how they did this? Or what route they took? Any helpful information related to this, or interactive maps would be very appreciated.

You can view the picture right here:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The URL you reference gives an image, not a map, so it might just be a mockup of something they would like to do.

It is also possible that this app is for a limited geographical region and they figured out the parcel information by hand (or got it from their city).

It's hard to tell with just an image.

Comment: Haha, the image is the screenshot of the map of course.

I've actually figured out how it works. They get their outlined data from a seperate company that does this geographic work.

Comment: Okay, why don't you make an answer that says that and accept your answer so that this question gets closed.  :-)